# Is $\overline{\operatorname{int}_{Y}(F)}\subset\overline{\operatorname{int}(F)}$ if $Y$ is closed and $F\subset Y\subset X$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of $X$. Suppose that $F\subset Y$. If $\operatorname{int}_{Y}(F)$ denotes the interior of $F$ with respect to the subspace topology of $Y$, is it true that

> $\overline{\operatorname{int}_{Y}(F)}\subset\overline{\operatorname{int}(F)}$?

Here both closures are taken with respect to the topology on $X$.

**My attempt:**

I know $\operatorname{int}_{Y}(F)=\operatorname{int}(F\cup(X\setminus Y))\cap Y$.

I was able to show that $x\in\overline{\operatorname{int}(F)}$ whenever $x\in\operatorname{int}(Y)\cap\overline{\operatorname{int}_{Y}(F)}$. So I just need to show that the same is true for $x\in (Y\setminus \operatorname{int}(Y))\cap \overline{\operatorname{int}_{Y}(F)}$. That is:

> For all $x\in Y\setminus\operatorname{int}(Y)$, if $x\in \overline{\operatorname{int}(F\cup(X\setminus Y))\cap Y} (=\overline{\operatorname{int}_{Y}(F)})$, then $x\in \overline{\operatorname{int}(F)}$.

I would appreciate any input. I am starting to think this mightn't be true.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for example $X = \Bbb{R}^2$, $Y = \Bbb{R} \times \{0\}$, and $F = [0, 1] \times \{0\}$.